# unit test console output

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, trace

IF I am testing something related to an error, I might want to see the message or stack trace in the console initially. After I'm satisfied with the test I typically do not want to have the console cluttered with anything that might help quickly spot and diagnose a failing test. When refactoring though, it is sometimes useful to once again output additional info. So I have lots of lines scattered about that I comment / uncomment, like:

```
// System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
```

What is a cleaner way to do this?

Cheers,
Berryl

=== EDIT

Here is an example of what I mean, updated to use a Log service as per Josh's suggestion here.

As a unit test, I want to assert that an error will be displayed to the user, in this case because there is a duplicate name for a new department. I can and do automate that the message is being generated with the correct content.

The message also has to pass a basic smell test that can't be automated though - is it a well structured sentence that most users will quickly understand and know how to fix? I don't want to have to fire up the ui and get a user to make sure it isn't outright silly, so I want to eyeball it by printing it out. And as I alluded to earlier, this is just noise except for the few times the message changes.

```
    [Test]
    public void WhenThePropertyIsChanged_IfDuplicateIsFound_DuplicateNameIsPartOfBrokenRuleMessage()
    {
        const string newName = "Blah";
        // force a duplicate
        _dao.Stub(x => x.FindByName(newName)).Return(new Department(newName)); 

        var vm = _masterVm.Departments.Last();

        vm.Name = newName;
        var msg = vm.GetBrokenRules().First().Description;
        Log.Service.WriteLine(msg); <=== print it
        Assert.That(msg, Is.StringContaining(newName));
        Assert.That(vm.BrokenRules.First().Description, Is.EqualTo(msg));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your logging statements into a service and code to an interface.

```
public interface ILoggingService
{
    void WriteLine(String msg);
}
```

Create a static class that allows access to the logging service, but allows you to set the service.

```
internal static class Log
{
    private static ILoggingService _loggingService;
    internal static ILoggingService Service
    {
        get{ return _loggingService ?? (_loggingService = new DefaultLoggingService()); }
        set{ _loggingService = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can implement a service in just your tests that writes to the Debug stream.

```
public class DebugLoggingService: ILoggingService
{
    public void WriteLine(String msg)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}

Log.Service = new DebugLoggingService();
```

Your code can stay the same now, and you only have to change your DebugLoggingService by commenting out the lines there. Or better yet, you could wrap it in a `#if DEBUG ... #endif` statement.

Comment: Pretty slick. If you were using Log4Net anyway would you still implement the service or does Log4Net do that??

Comment: @Berryl -- I typically stick even my third party stuff behind an interface boundary so I don't get "framework" locked. I use Entlib a lot for logging, but I still use service boundaries like above. In that way, if I ever want to swap out my logging framework for something else I can.

Answer (score 1):

It's by better to use assertions that console output. If the computer can display it, it also can verify it, a lot faster than you can.

If you do not have true unit tests, and are testing manually, you could use [Log4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Ports), so you can easily tune the trace level you want.

Comment: It wouldn't be a unit test without an assertion; what I'm talking about is fine tuning type stuff that is sometimes useful in *addition* to the assertion.

Comment: @Berryl: agreed, but not everyone is using the unit testing term for the same thing. I seemed to me that you might not be writing automatic unit tests, hence my comment. <br>That being said, you should generally not need print statement. Do you have them in your code or in your tests ? Those in tests shall definitively be converted into assertions. <br>Nevertheless, the Log4j or whatever advice remains.

Comment: @phillipe. See edit at end of original post to understand the motivation for the print and a sample test case with it. The total percentage of unit tests that will merit any print out is very small. If I knew log4net well I probably would use it in someway but Josh's suggestion is a definite upgrade over what I was doing before. Cheers